# Why would a nightly full backup of our SQL Server database grow 30 GB over night and then shrink again the next day?

Tags: sql-server-2005, backup

We run SQL Server 2005 and have a database that's about 100 GB (the MDF is 100GB and the LDF is 34 GB).

Our maintenance plan takes a full database back up every night. It's set up to

This backup size is usually around 95-100 GB but it all of a sudden grew to 120 GB, then 124 GB then 130 GB then back to 100 GB over 4 consecutive days.

Does anyone know what could cause this? I don't believe we added and then removed that much data in such a short period of time.

Answer (score 0):

If your backup is larger than the MDF, this means you have a lot of log activity recorded too. SQL Server notes data changes that happen during a full backup and does a "mini" log backup to capture this.

I'd say that you need to change Index maintenance and backup timings

Comment: Thank you. We reorganize our indexes every week, should this be done more often? What do you mean about backup timings? We backup our transaction log every hour and do a full backup every night.

Comment: No need to rebuild indexes unless you have a lot of data changes: sound like you have. You can do it smarter http://sqlfool.com/2011/06/index-defrag-script-v4-1/. And the backup size growing then shrinking sounds like the a smaller backup after index maintenance. I guess I'm trying to say don't worry about it. I would make sure that no other jobs or actions occur during your full backup